# Chazzan Recordings Online (Nusach Sefard)

Tags: tefilla, chazzan-prayer-leader, nusach-sefard, high-holidays

Is there anywhere online where I can find recordings of *Nusach Sefard* liturgy, as sung by the *chazzan*? There are plenty of websites dedicated to liturgy according to *Nusach Ashkenaz* and some *Chabad-Lubavitch* ones here are there, but barely any *Nusach Sefard* recordings from what I've seen or found. [Epes-A-Nigun](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCQ709Vl4e-xa4L9PgTakIIQ) on YouTube has a few recordings, but no High Holiday ones. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By far the largest website i have found that has gone through the effort to collect recordings from all nusachot is this website: http://offtonic.com/nusach/index.html

> — a rapidly growing collection of Jewish liturgical tunes. The goal is to compile a database of every melody for every Jewish liturgical text. Can it be done? No. But it won't stop me from trying!

Comment: B''H Thank you for the answer. The website is amazing; I wish he had some sound recordings though. But definitely something to start with.

Comment: @EzraHoerster Click on the links for Nusach Sites, he has an extensive collection of websites that have their own recordings

Answer (score 1):

[Nusachtefillah.com](http://www.nusachtefillah.com/) is a site dedicated to nusach, there you can listen to all tefillois from Shabbos, Rosh Chodesh to Rosh Hashana & Yom Kippur.

Comment: The OP asked for Nusach Sefard. As far as I can tell, those recordings are of Nusach Ashkenaz.

Comment: @DonielF - How can you tell? I have used this website before and the Shabbos Shacharis recordings are definitely Nusach Sefard.

Comment: The Mincha ones sound more like Ashkenaz than Sefard. Like I said - as far as I can tell. I don’t daven Sefard. But if you like them, why not give at least an upvote?

Comment: nusachtefillah.com is definitely nusach sfard. He says vayatzmach purkanei vikareiv meshichei.